# Spring Form Tag Error (Binding Result)

Tags: java, spring

I am teaching myself Spring Form tags, and have run into what is probably a simple error that I haven't been able to solve.  I get the following error when I launch this app in a browser:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'index' available as request attribute
```

I've tried most of the fixes that came up in a Google search to no avail.  Can someone spot where I went wrong?  Below are the relevant components.  Thanks very much.

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setupForm(ModelMap model) {
        Registration registration = new Registration();
        model.addAttribute("registration", registration);
        return "index";

    }


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("registration") Registration registration, Map model) {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

JSP (/index.jsp):

```
        <form:form commandName="index">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="12">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="email"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:password path="password"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

Command Object (Registration.java) :

```
public class Registration {
    private String password;
    private String email;
    // getters,setters
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your index page correct the following and try

`<form:form commandName="index">` to `<form:form commandName="registration">`

You can also do it like this if the above does not work

`<form:form modelAttribute="registration" commandName="registration">`

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Heggi!!  I'll accept your answer when the waiting period is up!!

Answer (score 1):

Facing same issue few days back, What i understood from hit and trail is, Index page is a static page and no processing happens before the same is rendered. In case i want to use a form model binding in index page i should have a controller's handler method which will create a Registration object and place the same in ModelAndView before index.jsp is rendered

add a method in your controller like the below and try

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/")
public ModelAndView initiate(){
ModelAndView objModView = new ModelAndView("/index.jsp");
objModView.addObject("registration",new Registration());
return objModView;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error which is seen is because when you submit the form you have to have a Binding Result associated with the @ModelAttribute annotation.

Try changing you code to this :

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("registration") Registration registration, BindingResult result, Map model){
          return "success";
       }
```

Also note that the Binding Result object should be followed immediately after the Model Attribute.

And if you are using two @ModelAttributes then each one should have its own binding result object which follows it.

Please refer the spring source guide for all the related documentation

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html